# C++. rand. Сделать более непостоянными случайные числа

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Проблема следующая: при каждом запуске программы выпадают одни и те же случайные числа. 
Пробовал решить ее следующими способом: 
Использовать функцию srand ( time(NULL) );, но тут опять проблема нужно делать паузы, использовал system("pause");, но ее использовать не совсем удобно, слишком много времени нужно. Пробовал в качестве параметра использовать случайное число, тоже не то. Можно ли показывать случайные числа каким либо другим способом?

Comment: я совсем не понял, почему нельзя использовать srand(time(NULL)). на что много времени нужно?

Comment: Все решил проблему, просто я использовал не в том месте srand(time(null));. Я использовал в функции, достаточно использовать в начале в начале программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) printf("%d ",rand());
```

так будут генерироваться с каждым запуском различные числа

нужна библиотека time.h

Answer (score 1):

Если time() не годится (секунда не успевает пройти), то м.б. микросекунды из gettimeofday() подойдут ?

Comment: а зачем чему-то проходить? один раз в начале программы устанавливаем srand, т.е. основание псевдослучайных чисел, и далее берем их из rand столь часто, сколько нужно

Comment: Так srand(time(NULL)) автор пишет, что использует.

Comment: так я и пишу, шо ничего не понял

Comment: srand нужно вызывать всего **один** раз при старте программы. Повторные вызовы не имеют смысла.

Comment: да в том все дело, что они заново устанавливают базу и вывод чисел начинается заново.

Comment: Не для данного вопроса, но м.б. ситуация, когда независимые процессы, реагируя на связанные события будут начинать при srand(time(0)) одинаковые последовательности rand().

Хотя в таком случае, я просто написал бы srand(time(0)+getpid());

Answer (score 1):

ну вообще все перечисленное - методы С
в C++ (ну может C++11, не уверен) есть [< random >](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/)

у эти генераторы хорошо описаны в "язык программирования С++" (издание 2014 года)